# Multilingual Switch Block just for link to other pages

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

How Can I hide the language link that is shown in black circle?
And I wonder to know how can I just show the inactive language pages and link to their pages(in the red square)

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the image, it seems that the unwanted language link is a published content. In that case, hide it is as simple as edit the content in the "Content" section and mark that content as "Not Published". In other case, if the link is not showed in the "Main page content" block but in another block, then you can go to /admin/structure/block and disable that block. Also, if the link is in "Main page content" and you are going to modify your home page, maybe using Panels, that link will disappear.
For the second question, you can go to http://drupal.org/node/754264. There is a good discussion about "show only posts of the selected language". They also proposed the "Language Switcher" module http://drupal.org/project/language_switcher, which could fit you if you use as selection filter the inactive languages.